# BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu '::1/64': address/prefix length mismatch '64'

Tags: networking, bind

I set up a new ubuntu 20.04 server and installed BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu. Then I copied the bind configuration from my old ubuntu 16.04.7 running BIND 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu.

When I try to start bind on the new server I get this error.

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.options:15: '::1/64': address/prefix length mismatch '64'
```

Here is my /etc/bind/named.conf.options file.

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        dnssec-validation auto;
        auth-nxdomain no;

        dump-file "/var/cache/bind/named_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/cache/bind/named.stats";

        listen-on port 53 { 0.0.0.0/0; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
        allow-query { 0.0.0.0/0; ::/0; };
        version "DNS";

        allow-recursion {
                127.0.0.0/8;            ::1/64;
                10.10.0.0/24;           1000:1000:1000:1000::/56;
        };

        allow-transfer {
                127.0.0.1;              ::1;
        };

        disable-empty-zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa";

        notify yes;
        masterfile-format text;
};
```

What is wrong with this prefix?

What has changed in bind 9.16 cause same file works perfect with bind 9.10?

Answer (score 0):

In many places in the options you can manage what devices or what networks are allowed to transact with the DNS server.
When specifying single IP address, you need to either use binary all 1s mask, 32bit long for IPv4 (CIDR /32) and 128bit long for IPv6 (CIDR /128) or omit the mask. 
In case you are specifying the network, you should not over specify it.

`::1` is an IP address while the mask `/64` is suggesting a network so the mask is over specified.
If you wish to use `::1` IP address then mask should be `/128` or omitted like in the "allow-transfer" section.

`1000:1000:1000:1000::/56` subnet is incorrect because it is from range reserved by IETF

Global Unicast addresses are in `2000::/3` range,
Unique Local Unicast `fc00::/7`,
Link-scoped Unicast `fe80::/10`,
Multicast `ff00::/8`.
Other addresses are reserved.
If you don't use IPv6 in your network, I would recommend to remove them from your configuration.

Comment: Ok then, when I change ::1/64 to ::1/128 I get next error '1000:1000:1000:1000::/56': address/prefix length mismatch '56' Why this?

Comment: @ Thomas Aichinger I tested this config on BIND 9.16.1 and it doesn't complain about `1000:1000:1000:1000::/56`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 1000:1000:1000:1000::/56 is a fake cause I dont want to write the real address. But anyway this error is gone now. Thank you for your help.